# XSLT - Finding number of child td tags in parent tr tag

Tags: html, xslt, xpath, tags

I have a parent `tr` tag and want to know total number of `td` tags under it. In other words, is there a way to find out exact number of child tags under a parent tag.

Comment: You should clarify if you are indeed querying a **parent** `tr` tag, meaning you're querying form a `td` tag and actually want to count the sibling `td` tags. The current answers assume you are querying from the `tr` tag or its ancestor.

Comment: it would help greatly if you would include an input XML, and the desired output, coupled with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `count`

```
count(/tr[CURRENT_POSITION]/td)
```

### Example:

Assuming we are at first `tr`

```
count(/tr[1]/td)
```

The other way you can write using `position()` as well, while your are doing a loop

```
count(/tr[position()]/td)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a given input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td colspan="2">bbb</td>
    <td colspan="2">ccc</td>
</tr>
```

and a stylesheet like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="totalcells">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(td[not(@colspan)]) + sum(td/@colspan)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

we have an output like this:

```
<tr totalcells="5">
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td colspan="2">bbb</td>
        <td colspan="2">ccc</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: While this is a nice solution I guess the OP rather needs to know the other direction: "How many sibling `td` are there?" in order to set the colspan of first or last `td`.

Comment: Since the OP used `tr` and `td` tags, I assumed that it was an html table. If you are simply counting all `td` tags under `tr` (as in the example above), you would be mistaken if there are `colspan` attributes present in `td` nodes.